# Problem with Site.com Form Element

Tags: customer-community, error-messages, site.com, form

Am struck in building a site.com form element.

I build two pages(Home and Contact Us) in site.com for customer community. `Everyone can see Home page but only logged in user can see contact us page(build with authorization)`.

**My problem** : So I have two pages. Simple Texts on Home page and Contact us page has form for Lead object to insert a record when form is submitted from site.com and this page is for authorized users only. I can see home page without logging in and when I click on Contact Us Page it is redirecting me to login page and when I login to the community it redirecting to community and when I Click on Contact us menu it is `not showing the DEFAULT VIEW(FORM WHICH CONTAINS LEAD OBJECT FIELDS) but it showing me the ERROR VIEW`. I don't know why it is showing me error view. Then I removed that form element and added once again but issue continues. So I need help on this. I want to show that default view form to users.

**Below is DEFAULT VIEW FROM PREVIEW PAGE**

[image]

**when i logged in and click on contact us page it should show me default view but it is showing me error view**

[image]

Comment: can you use debug log and see if there is any error coming?

Comment: I checked in debug with that logged in customer user but no error is found in debug log all finished successfully.

Comment: Seems like issue with object accessibility

Comment: Ohh you are saying that logged in user does'nt have access to that lead object. right?

Comment: I agree with @ratan, you need to check that the logged in users profile has appropriate access to the lead object and fields, as well as to the Visualforce pages and apex classes.  You set all these in the Profile settings.  Just setting them on the site or in community management isn't enough.